# How to find connector type

Tags: connector, cables, plug

I try to identify the following connector type but do not get it with https://connectorbook.com/identification.html Can you maybe give me a tip?

(width auf the socket is about 8 mm, of the plug 6 mm)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please add dimensions, pin pitch, and some more pictures showing the plug and socket from different angles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I am pleased to see you using my Indenticonn utility. Thank you.

To identify those connectors:

1. Measure the exact pitch, in mm
2. Identify the latching mechanism and the keying (if any). If you post various pictures of the male PCB header and the plug by itself, showing the latching method, we can tell you what it uses.
3. Look through this section: https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=prismatic_conn

**EDIT**

Thank you for the additional pictures. The latched connectors are [Molex SL connectors](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=prismatic_latch_conn&s=SL%2070543%2070553%2070107%2C%2070430). Unfortunately, I don't have any information about the unlatched connectors.

Comment: Thank you very much again! Now I get it with your tool https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=prismatic_latch_conn&s=CDR%2C%20CDH Manuf: Adam tech
Series: CDR, CDH